# What is a good way to establish words that should not have any response?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

Many phrases such as "lol" or "ok" should not be triggering a response from a chatbot (Dialogflow), but by default, there is no specific setup for that. Dialogflow just falls into

One option I have created is a "do_not_respond" intent which has training phrases like "OK" and "LOL". But I'm not sure what problems I could be creating with this approach. How have you solved such an issue?

Comment: I think this question is a bit too open ended for stackoverflow. But you should consider getting a dataset of chats, and measure words the chat is likely to end on.

Comment: You have already answered your question: Train your model.